# vb.net register hotkey "capslock"

Tags: vb.net, registerhotkey

is there possible to register "CapsLock" as a hotkey instead of registering 2keys? i dont want to use ctrl+key, alt+key. I want to toggle "CapsLock" to start/break my loop. Like if i toggle on the capslock, the loop will run and so on. I solve this making a timer and checking the keystate of capslock whether is it on or off. but i dont like it, coz my application is keep showing the notifyballon message i make when toggling the capslock every time the timer's tick. so im hoping someone can help me with this.

im using this code to register some of my hotkey, and is this possible to edit for "CapsLock"?

```
RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1, MOD_CTRL, Keys.Oem3)
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run the code for the keyup event on the form. Use an if statement to see if the capslock key was pressed, and run loop if it did. Have a boolean value change each time you press the capslock key to tell the loop when to quit.

```
If e.KeyData = Keys.CapsLock Then
    boolvalue = Not boolvalue
        While boolvalue
            ' Do your thing.
        End While
End If
```